# rpm package: some conflicts between libiconv glibc iconv

Tags: rpm

Description:
    I want to make a libiconv rpm for myself, but i find some conflicts between the libiconv and glibc iconv

```
I list them here
    bin/iconv
    share/man/man3/iconv.3.gz
    share/man/man3/iconv_close.3.gz
    share/man/man3/iconv_open.3.gz 

So, how can i solve this problem?
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put it in another place than `/usr`.

I don't know how your spec file is written exactly, but that would mean changing the `--prefix` option of `./configure`.